# How to set Osmdroid to never expire tiles?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to set up Osmdroid to use pre-fetched tiles in offline mode. I downloaded an area in ZIP format. The problem is that zip file has 100 MB size and this will reduce performance of the app and in some devices with limited resources, the app crashes.
I unzipped file and I changed the tile extension to .tile and everything was ok until yesterday. Yesterday osmdroid expired all tile and deleted them! 
I want to know is there a way to set up Osmdroid to never expire tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend using GEMF format instead of ZIP.  It is a format designed for efficent rendering on a mobile device.  If you use Mobile Atlas Creator and just choose the GEMF format and copy the file like the zip file and it just works.  There is little difference in the size of the file but the GEMF decoder in Osmdroid needs far less resources and is quicker especialy with the inital open than the zip decoder.

Comment: GEMF is a lot faster than zip file. But what is difference(s) between SQLite and GEMF? Which one is better? which one is faster?

Comment: I have not tried SQLite, so no idea.  GEMF worked for me it was designed for the job.  There is an issue in the osmdroid tracker with more discussion.

Comment: do i need to add any tilesource or tileprovider code for this to work? Do you have example code of using a gemf file?

Comment: You do not need any code just copy the file to the right place.  If it's one of the standard online tile providers it just works...